# twistd -n web not working with Klein and Python3

Tags: python-3.x, twisted, klein-mvc

i'm try to run twistd web with Klein and got a lot of issues.
Even if try run it from an example - got the same results.
[Source](https://klein.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/2-twistdtap.html)

```
from klein import Klein
app = Klein()

@app.route('/')
def hello(request):
    return "Hello, world!"

resource = app.resource
```

Then run it (in this example, the file above is saved as twistdPlugin.py:

`$ twistd -n web --class=twistdPlugin.resource`

Errors:

`sh-3.2# twistd -n web --class=twistdPlugin.resource
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/twistd", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Twisted==17.9.0', 'console_scripts', 'twistd')()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 29, in run
    app.run(runApp, ServerOptions)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 657, in run
    config.parseOptions()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 624, in parseOptions
    usage.Options.parseOptions(self, options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/usage.py", line 267, in parseOptions
    self.subOptions.parseOptions(rest)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/usage.py", line 255, in parseOptions
    self._dispatch[optMangled](optMangled, arg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/usage.py", line 411, in <lambda>
    fn = lambda name, value, m=method: m(value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/web/tap.py", line 121, in opt_class
    classObj = reflect.namedClass(className)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/reflect.py", line 173, in namedObject
    module = namedModule('.'.join(classSplit[:-1]))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/reflect.py", line 159, in namedModule
    topLevel = __import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twistdPlugin'`

How to be with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this 1 of 2 ways. First way would be to add the directory with your source code to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. This is the easiest method.

```
PYTHONPATH=$(pwd) twistd -n web --class twistdPlugin.resource
```

Or you could make a virtualenv and install your `twistdPlugin` module there. This way you won't have to mess with environment variables yourself.

The tl;dr of the matter is that twistd used to source the current directory in <s>Python 2</s> Twisted < 16.4 but it doesn't do that anymore with <s>Python 3</s> the lastest Twisted. In other words, twistd expects all modules to be importable. Despite being a nuisance at times, this design makes twistd apps portable.

Comment: Actually not related to Python 3 at all.  On neither Python 2 nor Python 3 does the most recent release of Twisted's `twistd` load plugins found at ${PWD}.  The change was introduced in 16.4 (as an unintentional, unannounced side-effect of unrelated maintenance), I believe.  See https://twistedmatrix.com/pipermail/twisted-python/2016-September/030780.html

Comment: Thanks, maybe you know better wait to run Klein on server as web app? Local it's working good and i try run on server like do with Flask with Apache2 but for Klein it's not working.

Comment: How's your Apache setup? Flask is usually run via a WSGI server which Klein doesn't need and won't work with. I've run Klein behind both Apache and Nginx using a proxy with no issues.